# where is mistake in my MySql query for create trigger

Tags: mysql, random, triggers, phpmyadmin, passwords

I have a stu table that has many column(name,lname,username,pass and else) and I want to after or before every new user registration insert a random unique string with length 8 or 6 character of numbers and alphabetic letters for password of every new user in first login.
after many search found this code:

```
    declare ready int default 0;
    declare rnd_str text;

    while not ready do
        set rnd_str := lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)), 10, 36), 6, 0);
        if not exists (select * from stu where pass = rnd_str) then
            set new.pass = rnd_str;
            set ready := 1;
        end if;
    end while;
```

I try to create trigger by phpmyadmin and after click on GO button give me an error.

who can help me to solve that?

error in phpmyadmin is this text:

"One or more errors have occured while processing your request:

```
The following query has failed: "CREATE TRIGGER `set_random_8char_pass` BEFORE INSERT ON `stu` FOR EACH ROW declare ready int default 0; declare rnd_str text; while not ready DO set rnd_str := lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)), 10, 36), 6, 0); if not exists (select * from stu where pass = rnd_str) then set new.pass = rnd_str; set ready := 1; end if; end while;"

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare ready int default 0; declare rnd_str text; while not ready' at line 1
```

"

thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.

read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html

So your trigger code should be something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `set_random_8char_pass` BEFORE INSERT ON `stu` FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
  declare ready int default 0;
  declare rnd_str text;

  while not ready DO set rnd_str := lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)),        10, 36), 6, 0);
     if not exists (select * from stu where pass = rnd_str)
     then
       set new.pass = rnd_str;
       set ready := 1;
     end if;
   end while;
END
```